# Laravel Static and Non-static Methods

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel Framework one can use Model's Methods as Static and also Non-static, For example you can get a user from Databse like this:

```
User::where('id', 1)->first();
```

and also like this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->where('id', 1)->first();
```

how can you do this in PHP?
because as far as i know a method can only be Static or Non-Static but not both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is being done via the magic method `__callStatic` which is creating a new instance of the model then calling the method on it. This particular method, `where`, doesn't exist on the model and is being handled by the magic method `__call` which is calling this method on an Eloquent Builder instance.

[PHP.net Manual - OOP - Overloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) `__callStatic` `__call`

[Laravel - Github - Eloquent Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1738) `__callStatic`

[Laravel - Github - Eloquent Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1718) `__call`

Comment: methods are methods, properties are properties (i assume property is what you are meaning by 'attribute')... also the term "attribute(s)" has special meaning in terms of Eloquent models